# Using grep in a loop and writing output to file

Tags: for-loop, grep

I have 2 files, one contains strings I am looking for in the second file.

file_1 looks like this :

```
ITCTES7178448
ITCTES6985234
ITCTES6933029
ITCTES6933013
ITCTES6917957
ITC7313477
```

file_2 looks like this :

```
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7125972;ELS;included;;LE4161;23313;52923
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7125944;ELS;included;;LE702;192;54862
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7126396;ELS;included;;LE513;3678;50366
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7394904;ELS;included;;LE10275698;28763;54373
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7126032;ELS;included;;LE702;192;54862
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7395201;ELS;included;;LE39944153;56015;0
Pos_IDEAL_ITCTES7366472;ELS;included;;LE1259193;38976;62891
```

I've tried with the following command :

```
for i in `cat file_1`; do grep "$i" file_2 >> results;done
```

Although I know there are several correspondences, I always end up with only 1 line in `results`, which corresponds to the last grep being processed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure you have `>> results`, rather than `> results`?

Comment: Why don't you just use `grep -f file_1 file_2`?

Comment: Becase `grep -f` doesn't work either : I end up with only one line also

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I think some other part of your script is overwriting the file.

Comment: BTW, I had to modify the sample `file_1`, because there aren't any matches with `file_2`.

Comment: Are you sure there are really multiple matches between the files?

Comment: Did you create the file on a Windows machine? Try using `dos2unix` to fix the line endings.

Comment: @Barmar : damn you nailed it (dos2unix). Problem solved :)